Solving $Ax=0$ with column-deleted determinants
In a textbook exercise (Kostrykin, $2004$, "Introduction to Algebra, Part $1$", Ch.$3$, sect.$3$, no.$4$), I have a homogeneous system of linear equations with $n-1$ equations and $n$ unknowns:
$$
\begin{matrix} 
a_{11} x_1 + \ldots + a_{1n} x_n = 0 \\ 
\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots \\ 
a_{n-1,1}x_1 + \ldots + a_{n-1,n}x_n = 0
\end{matrix} 
$$
The system has rank $r = n - 1$. The problem is to prove that the solution to the system will contain one column vector:
$$ X^0 = [D_1, -D_2, D_3, \ldots, (-1)^{n-1} D_n], $$
where $D_i$ is the determinant of the matrix formed from the original matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ by removing its $i$-th column.
--
It is evident and easy to prove that the null space of such matrix contains only one vector (Rank–nullity theorem). Most of the elements in this vector are zero because the determinants have linearly dependent rows (columns). The problem arises with explaining why these "quasi-cofactors" with alternating signs form the elements of the solution vector. This is similar to Cramer's rule, but for $Ax=0$ systems.

Consider the $i^\text{th}$ entry of $AX^0$, which we need to prove is zero for every $i$. This is
$$ a_{i1}D_1 - a_{i2}D_2 + \dots + (-1)^na_{in}D_n. $$
But that expression is the determinant of the matrix you get by adding row $i$ on top of the original matrix $A$:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_{i1} & a_{i2} & \cdots & a_{in} \\ a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots && \vdots \\ a_{1,n-1} & a_{2,n-1} & \cdots & a_{n,n-1} \end{bmatrix}, $$
expanded by cofactors along the first row. That determinant has to be zero because row 1 and row $i+1$ are the same.

Also called Laplace or cofactor expansion.
